# mysql update a table with LOAD DATA

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have someone working on a csv (generated from my table) where they will be updating some fields by hand. This may happen multiple times. I'd like to take the modified csv and update my existing table.

From my understanding, I will need to create a tmp table and then use that to update the existing table. So I can create the temporary table, but how can I iterate through that table and use it to update the existing table?

My sql querying skills are pretty basic. I think its possible, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Use the `REPLACE` keyword in `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: A little more detail in this question would make it possible to answer. Right now this is pretty much a hypothetical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSV you are generating that gets edited, you must include a unique value that will allow you to match the edited record to the original record. Make sure the user doesn't change that column! Also, make sure you have a unique key on that column.

You can then import the edited data into a table with the same (or at least very similar) structure as the original table.

Once the data is imported, you can use an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... statement to update the original table. Here's an example:

Main data table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_table`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (
    `id`        INT(10) UNSIGNED    NOT NULL        AUTO_INCREMENT                  COMMENT 'Primary Key',
    `fld1`      VARCHAR(100)        NULL,
    `fld2`      VARCHAR(100)        NULL,
    `fld3`      VARCHAR(100)        NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Temporary table for edited CSV import:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `import_table`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `import_table` (
    `n_id`      INT(10)             NOT NULL    COMMENT 'Original Primary Key',
    `n_fld1`    VARCHAR(100)        NULL,
    `n_fld2`    VARCHAR(100)        NULL,
    `n_fld3`    VARCHAR(100)        NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Simulated data before export and editing:

```
INSERT INTO `my_table`
(`fld1`,`fld2`,`fld3`)
VALUES
('John','Doe','Atlanta'),
('Jane','Smith','New York'),
('Bill','Howe','San Antonio'),
('Harry','Fields','Paris');
```

Simulate the imported, edited records:

```
INSERT INTO `import_table`
(`n_id`,`n_fld1`,`n_fld2`,`n_fld3`)
VALUES
(1,'John','Doe','Decatur, IL'),
(2,'Jane','Smithsonian','New York, NY'),
(3,'Bill','Bellweather','San Antonio, TX'),
(4,'Harry','Belefonte','Houston, TX');
```

Merge the imported, edited records bak into the main table:

```
INSERT INTO `my_table`
(`id`,`fld1`,`fld2`,`fld3`)
SELECT `n_id`,`n_fld1`,`n_fld2`,`n_fld3` 
FROM `import_table`
ON DULPICATE KEY UPDATE
`fld1` = `n_fld1`,
`fld2` = `n_fld2`,
`fld3` = `n_fld3`;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a temporary table. Just make sure the CSV file includes the primary key of the table. Then you can use the `REPLACE` modifier in `LOAD DATA INFILE`. From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html):

> If you specify `REPLACE`, input rows replace existing rows. In other words, rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique index as an existing row.